# How does pdfcrowd.com generates pdf

Tags: php, pdf

I want to develop some script which generates pdf. I tried dompdf, tcpdf etc but seems they do not much. I have found one online service which generates pdf online, pdfcrowd.com, and their pdf looks perfect. Does anybody know how they do that and how to get the same effect with php?

Answer (score 0):

Presumbly if it were well known and easy to do, others would have competing services.  There are a few options that I've found; the most common is to use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) to generate your PDFs, though that may not scale well.  There is also a commercial product called [PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/) that seems to work really well, though it's only free for non-commercial use, and that adds a small logo to the first page.

There are no options that are directly in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I stumbled across it as part of some research I was doing, so it might be useful to someone else also.

I'm pretty sure that pdfcrowd.com (and all the other services like it) is just a front end for the open source project wkhtmltopdf - http://wkhtmltopdf.org/. I've downloaded and compiled it on my computer and the results are the same.